# How to send an email with attachment in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, email-attachments

Now I can send an email without attachment :

```
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

But how can I send an email with attachment?

Comment: Refer to this link here is the resolved http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_mailer-with-attachment

Comment: Check this amazing article https://www.phparticles.com/wordpress/how-to-use-wp-mail-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 <?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Comment: how can i add html content?

Comment: as per documentation The default content type is ‘text/plain’ which does not allow using HTML. You can set the content type of the email either by using the ‘wp_mail_content_type‘ filter ( see example below), or by including a header like “Content-type: text/html”. Be careful to reset ‘wp_mail_content_type’ back to ‘text/plain’ after you send your message, though, because failing to do so could lead to unexpected problems with e-mails from WP or plugins/themes.

Answer (score 7):

Refer below e.g.

```
$attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip');
$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
wp_mail('test@test.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components' );

function mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components( $components ) {
    $components['attachments'][] = 'full path of your PDF file';

    return $components;
}
```

Comment: That only works for users of the Contact Form 7 plugin.  The author is asking about wp_mail.